# How to write pallet rename data migration?

Tags: pallet, storage, migration, trie

I want to rename one of our `collective` pallet instances to be visible in the PolkaddotJs App.

I think the best option would be to migrate raw data.

I assume that all pallet data has the same trie path prefix.

So I can do a copy of all keys with this prefix.

Will this approach work?

Rename could be a common operation. Could anybody refer relevant examples?

Another alternative is to have two pallets instances running, filter out calls to old pallet. Migrate each storage using typed interface. I think this approach is overkill. I need actually do this for 2 pallets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that all pallet data has the same trie path prefix.

Yes, this makes it much easier to migration.
There are [move_pallet](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/migration/index.html) and `move_storage_from_pallet` which can help.

There is even a test in the `collective` pallet to test these functions [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/940a458a8eaf05fdeda441dad82b2df186bf260e/frame/collective/src/tests.rs#L1387). Something like:

```rust
let old_pallet = "OldCollective";
let new_pallet = <Collective as PalletInfoAccess>::name();
frame_support::storage::migration::move_pallet(
    new_pallet.as_bytes(),
    old_pallet.as_bytes(),
);
```

Maybe someone else can point you to best-practices when it comes to renaming pallets.
The only thing that comes to my mind now is that: If you are doing this on a para-chain; it is important that the migration stays within the block weight limit. The `try-runtime` command prints the consumed weight relative to the block weight on completion so you can use that as indication but should still over-estimate.

Comment: AFAIK, there are only a few keys in the collective storage. I think the weight is totally fine.

Comment: Yea but it all goes into the PoV - so if the maps hold a lot of values this will increase.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Substrate/Polkadot "official" pallet prefix migration example.

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9115/files#diff-1dee027b2fa4c245bc171233ac07ec714f3fdc9a83a0f428adf67a2966049717R59-R62
- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/3265